# C# - strange event behaviour when subscribed without handler type

Tags: c#, events, .net-3.5

I am building a game project using C# .NET 3.5, and have mistyped a couple of the event subscriptions, but the resulting code still compiles and acts very strangely.

Normally when you subscribe to a C# event, you would declare the type of event handler (a delegate) and the name of the function that will actually handle the event, as follows:

```
myObject.StateChanged += new EventHandler(ObjectStateChanged);

private void ObjectStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // handle event here...
    }
```

What I've written in a few places is this:

```
MyObject.StateChanged += ObjectStateChanged;
```

So it subscribes to the event without explicitly declaring the event handler type. This produces all kinds of strange behaviour, mostly duplicate calls (in one playtest the event handler was called 4 times when the event was fired once). The code compiles though, and when replacing `+= ObjectStateChanged` with `+= new EventHandler(ObjectStateChanged)`, it runs normally.

So, my question is: in this circumstance, is the behaviour well-defined, and what should the code actually do?

Comment: There is no diiference between codes. Most probably you attach to the same event multiple times.

Comment: I've added an extra comment. The operation is different with the shortened version - it runs completely OK with the long version, `+= new EventHandler(ObjectStateChanged)`

Comment: Alex, `Goto FirstComment;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all

`myObject.StateChanged += new EventHandler(ObjectStateChanged);`

is equivalent to

`myObject.StateChanged += ObjectStateChanged;`.

**It's just a shorthand version of first syntax.**

Second, handler is called multiple times since you `might have hooked a delegate multiple time` using `+=`.

So, what you should do is prior of hooking a delegate, make sure you first unhook in case already hooked:

```
myObject.StateChanged -= ObjectStateChanged;
myObject.StateChanged += ObjectStateChanged;
```

Comment: Yes, correct. The shorthand notation is called _method group conversion_, technically. It was introduced in C# 2.0 (with Visual Studio 2005). At the same time it was allowed that the signature did not match exactly, for example you can have a method `void M(object sender, object args)` and still use `EventHandler h = M;` even if the second parameter type (`object`) of `M` is less specific than that of `EventHandler` delegate (read `EventArgs`).